# unable to add border color to input on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to change the border color on an onClick event.

If a particular radio button, such as 'Other' is checked, and the user tries to save, I wanted to change the border color to red to let the user know they must enter a value in the input.

```
$('#nextsales3Btn').on('click', function() {
  var ratestructure = $('input[name="ratestructure"]:checked').val();  // radio button
  var otherstructure = $('#otherratein').val();

  if(ratestructure == "Other" && otherstructure == "")
  {
    $('#otherratein').css('border', 'red');
    console.log('here');
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('all good');
  }
});
```

The above logic works.  I can see 'here' in the console when the radio button is checked and the input is empty, but I cannot seem to change the border color of the input.

I tried to use the following to no avail:

```
$('#otherratein').css('border-color', 'red');
```

No success there.

How can I make this work?

*** EDIT ***

Here is how the HTML looks:

```
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group"> 
           <label id="ratestructureLabel">Required Rate Structure:</label>                                     
           <br/> 
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="allin" value="all-in"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="yesebiz">All-In</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="allindest" value="all-inD"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="allindest">All-In, subject to Destinations</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="allinori" value="all-inO"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="allinori">All-In, subject to Origins</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="boforindest" value="bofOD"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="boforindest">BOF, subject to Origins & Destination</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="pernote2" value="pernote2"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="pernote2">Per Note 2</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="surcharges" value="surcharges"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="surcharges">Surcharges per tariff</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check form-check-inline"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="otherrate" value="Other Rate"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="otherrate">Other:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" name="otherstructure" id="otherrateIn" placeholder=""> 
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Could you show the html ?

Comment: inspect the element and see what is overriding the color. Impossible to tell on our end. But it you are going to set border, you need to assign all properties. The `'border-color'` should be fine.

Comment: Radio buttons and checkboxes don't have a border to style. Also, are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 - There is an input that I am trying to change, not the radio button or checkbox.

Comment: You posted `$('#otherrate').css('border-color', 'red');` and `$('#otherrate')` is a radio button: `<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="otherrate" value="Other Rate">`

Comment: Are you trying to change `otherrate` or `otherratein`?  if the former, it doesn't work as you need to set the border style.  If the latter, it doesn't work because you have a typo - you should have a capital I: `#otherrateIn`

Comment: I ended up adding a class to the input and now I am able to change the border.  Upvote for everyone who helped me.  Thank you.

Comment: @j08691 - I saw what you were talking about.  That was a typo.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the HTML and added a class to the actual input.  Then referenced that class in the jQuery and I was able to change the border of the input.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

**Definition and Usage
The border property is a shorthand property for:**

*border-width
border-style (required)
border-color*

so:

```
 border: 5px solid red;
```

at javascript:

```
$('#otherrate').css('border', '5px solid red');
```

Answer (score 1):

Only applying a color can get no results at all. You can try applying the following:

```
$('#otherrate').css('border', '1px solid red')
```

Even though I highly  recommend applying as CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

*border-color* and *border* are not same.

`$('#otherrate').css('border-color', 'red');` should work.

```js
$('#otherrate').css('border-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="otherrate"/>
```

In case of *border* property color name should be use with *border-width* and *border-style* property:

```js
$('#otherrate').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="otherrate"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `||` instead of `&&` because if any one of the condition is true you want to show border .Also , i have given class to your `div` which have `Others` radio-button inside it to give border to whole div. i.e :

```js
$('#nextsales3Btn').on('click', function() {
  var ratestructure = $('input[name="ratestructure"]:checked').val();  // radio button
  var otherstructure = $('#otherrate').val();

  if(ratestructure == "Other Rate" || otherstructure == "")
  {
    $('.otherrate').css('border', '1px solid red');
    console.log('here');
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
  //removing border
   $('.otherrate').css('border', '');
    console.log('all good');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group"> 
           <label id="ratestructureLabel">Required Rate Structure:</label>                                     
           <br/> 
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="allin" value="all-in"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="yesebiz">All-In</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="allindest" value="all-inD"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="allindest">All-In, subject to Destinations</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="allinori" value="all-inO"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="allinori">All-In, subject to Origins</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="boforindest" value="bofOD"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="boforindest">BOF, subject to Origins & Destination</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="pernote2" value="pernote2"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="pernote2">Per Note 2</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="surcharges" value="surcharges"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="surcharges">Surcharges per tariff</label>                                         
           </div>
           <div class="form-check form-check-inline otherrate"> 
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ratestructure" id="otherrate" value="Other Rate"> 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="otherrate">Other:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" name="otherstructure" id="otherrateIn" placeholder=""> 
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <button id="nextsales3Btn">Check</button>
```